# C# mysql one return last_insert_id

Tags: c#, mysql, methods, last-insert-id

I am trying to create a method in which I can exequte mysql UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT query. The method must work when with an INSERT I ask or do not ask the `last_insert_id()`. Below is the code that I have at the moment:

```
public int executeUID(MySqlCommand msCommand)
{
  try
  {
    this.Open();

    msCommand.Connection = this.msCon;

    return int.Parse(msCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
  }
  catch (MySqlException ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  finally
  {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

The problem with this is is that when I use an insert query that returns a `last_insert_id()` the method works greatly. But when the query doesn't return an `last_insert_id()` the method malfunctions. How can I get this method to work?

Comment: You say *the method malfunctions*
: why? What do you expect from this method? If your query is a select or something else, what do you want the method to return?

Comment: are you trying to get the rows effected by the transaction?

Comment: Can you show an example of query that works and an example of query that doesn't works? In case of _malfunctions_ do you get an exception? And, if yes, what is the error message?

Comment: This query works: INSERT INTO `event-lists` (`event_name`) VALUES ('" + strEventListName + "'); SELECT last_insert_id() AS elid
It returns the last_insert_id().

When I use this query: "INSERT INTO `event-list-units` (`callsign`, `description`, `location`) VALUES ('" + objEenheid.roepnr + "', '" + objEenheid.functie + "', '" + objEenheid.locatie + "'); INSERT INTO `event-list-units_event-lists` (`event-list`, `event-list-unit`) VALUES ('" + elid.ToString() + "', last_insert_id())"
I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

why not u use OUTPUT parametres, it will return the last inserted id.  [SqlParamet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

and if you know when LastInsertID can generate, then you can pass one more parameter to method, to tell that it is retriving insertedID, based on that parameter you can do some thing like this .

```
public int executeUID(MySqlCommand msCommand, bool Mode) //Mode==true means insertandRetriveLastID, false means =dont retrive last insertedit
{
  try
  {
    this.Open();

    msCommand.Connection = this.msCon;

    if(Mode)  //for getting last inserted id 
   {
      SqlParameter outParams= new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
      outParams.Direction =    ParameterDirection.Output;
      msCommand.Parameters.Add(outParams)
      msCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      var outputValue = cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value;  
   }
    else //if no inserted id is not there 
    {
       return msComand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // it will return No of Rows Affected. 
    }

  }
  catch (MySqlException ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  finally
  {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

PS : you need to tune it some more for better efficiency, as i gave some basic ideas how we can do it with out parameter

Comment: Yes, this should work. However, it's a very bad practice from the perspective of a clean code. A method should be doing only one thing, which is not the case here. The correct solution would be to split this into two new methods, not add a bool to switch between modes......

Comment: I want my code to be as clean as possible. So there must not me any method that does multiple things